# Soft question-What is a good path to learning pure math?

Tags: education, advice

So I just got accepted to college and I am going to pursue a double major in math and physics with the intention to eventually become a professor in theoretical physics. I am very interested in pure mathematics, but I do not quite know a good path to take. In what order should I take math courses through college? Exactly which classes should I take? When should I study math logic(such as set and number theory)and exactly what should I study in math logic?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: I think your math courses should include multivariable calculus, linear algebra, and differential equations

Comment: If you're proficient at calculus, you should probably start with real analysis and linear algebra.

Comment: I'm afraid the question is too broad.  Pure math is an extremely large area of knowledge. Even if you mean "pure math useful to physics" the answer will vary a lot depending on which part of physics you have in mind & what is your taste in mathematical abstractions (e.g. for quantum mechanics one could use differential equations, or C* algebras, or string diagram, or even quantum logic). So,  what exactly do you mean by pure math?

Comment: The question of which classes you should take is highly dependent on the university you're in (some have two or even three different levels of difficulty for math classes on the same material, others just one), on the way their programs are set up, on the ease with which you can "drop down" from more to less theoretical math courses. What you should do also depends a lot on your background - how much math you already know and how advanced your physics classes will be. Assuming you're a typical U.S. high school graduate with no experience in rigorous proof-oriented mathematics (for example,

Comment: even the great majority of high school graduates with a 5 in BC calculus are in this category), there are two big problems: (1) you haven't done enough proof-oriented math to know if you'll find it enjoyable and within your ability; (2) the kind of math you need immediately for physics is not the ideal kind to gain this kind of experience initially (particularly multivariable calculus and differential equations). Since you have a few months ahead of you, you could take some time to explore this side of things without thinking ahead to what you'll need for physics. It's sensible to use basic

Comment: analysis as an introduction to rigorous math. Assuming you already know the mechanical side of calculus, I'd recommend Burkill's *First Course in Mathematical Analysis* as an introduction. If you find that too difficult, then you could read something like Rotman's *Journey into Mathematics* to get used to proofs and then come back to Burkill. I wouldn't worry too much about studying logic until you're well into your studies in math. (Studying logic because you think it will help you with proofs is a bit like studying physics to learn to ride a bike - mathematicians use their innate ability...

Comment: as human beings to reason, not the fine analysis of reasoning that a study of logic provides. You learn to ride a bike by observing others doing it and then getting on and trying it yourself.)